# kibana changing date time field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am having strange problem with a time stamp field. the field is called tme. the document was loaded via logstash. I filtered the field doing the following.

```
date  {
    match => ["tme", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"]
    timezone => "America/New_York"
    target => "@timestamp"
}
```

I was looking at the document in elasticsearch-head. 
the value is

```
"tme": "2015-08-22T08:27:08",
```

however, when i view the document in kibana, the field is different.

```
tme August 22nd 2015, 04:27:08.000
```

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically the same date, just formatted differently and shown in your local timezone.

You can change the formatting in the settings

[image]

However, I'm afraid timezone support in Kibana 4 is still an [unresolved issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/95). It's been resolved in Kibana 3 but was somehow "left out" when they rewrote Kibana 4.

Comment: Timezone support is now available as of [Kibana 4.3](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1600) that's been released on Nov 24th, 2015.